# Siva Sahasra Nama Strota translation

Tags: shiva, translation-request, stotra

I’m searching for an English translation of the following Shiva Sahasra Nama Stotram
https://www.vignanam.org/veda/shiva-sahasra-nama-stotram-english.html

Can anyone provide a reference?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from the Mahabharata. And, yes we can get the required translation from the [Kamakoti.org website](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/mahabharata.html). There you will also find the context in which it was said in the Anushashana Parva of Mahabharata. Also, it gives the details of the Rishi and other Nyasa details associated with the Stotram etc..

The Stotram that you linked in question starts with -

> oṃ
>
> sthiraḥ sthāṇuḥ prabhurbhānuḥ pravaro varado varaḥ |
>  sarvātmā
> sarvavikhyātaḥ sarvaḥ sarvakaro bhavaḥ ‖ 1 ‖

And, to help you understand that I am talking about the same Stotram, I have highlighted the same verse in the quote given below.

> Nyasa: Asya Shiva Sahasranaama Stotra Maha Mantrasya Upamanyu Rishi
> Anushtup Chhanda Shri Samba Sada Shivo Devata; Sthira Sthaanur iti
> Beejam, Shrimaan Shri Vardhano Jahah iti Shaktih, Devatapati iti
> keelakam, Shri Samba Sadaa Shiva Prasada Sidhyarthey Japey Viniyogah
> Dhyana: Shantam Padmasanastam Shashidhara makutam Pancha Vaktram
> Trinetram, Shulam Vajramcha Khadgam Parashu mabhayadam Dakshina
> bhaagey vahantam/ Naagam Paasham Ghantam Pralaya hutaavahamsankusham
> Vaama bhagey, Naanaalankaara yuktam Sphatikamani niham Parvateesham
> Namaami/
>
> ( My salutations to Parvateesha the ever tranquil One as
> seated on a Lotus wearing half Moon on his Crown with Five Faces and
> Three Eyes carrying a Shula, Vajra, Khadga, Parashu and Abhaya or
> Safety Sign on his right side; Naaga Pasha or a curled serpent, Ghanta
> or a Huge Bell, Ankusha and Infernal Flames on his left side like a
> translucent crystal!) Puja: ‘Lam’ Prithivi Tatwatmaney Gandham
> Dharayami; ‘Ham’ Akasha Tatwatmaney Pushpai Pujayami; ‘Yam’ Vayu
> Tatwatmaney Dhupamaaghraapayaami; ‘Ram’Agneyyaatmaney Deepam
> Darshayaami; ‘Vam’ Amrita Tatweatmaney Amrita Naivedyam Nivedayami;
> ‘Sam’ Sampurnam Samarpayami’.
>
> - **SHIVA SAHASRANAMA STOTRA**
>
> **Om Sthirah Sthaanuh Prabhur Bheemah Pravaro Varado Varah, Sarvatmaa
> Sarva
> Vikhyaatah Sarvah Sarvakaro Bhavah**, Jati Charmi Shikhandi cha Sarva
> Bhavanah/ Harascha Hiranyakshascha Sarva Bhuta harah Prabhuh,
> Pravritthischa Nivrittischa Niyata Shasvato Dhruvah/ Shmashaana Vaasi
> Bhagavankhacharo Gochanordanah, Abhivadyo Mahakarma Tapaswi
> Bhutabhanah/ Unmatthaveshah Pracchannah Sarva Loka Prajapatih, Maha
> Rupo Maha Kaayo Vrisharupo Maha Yashah/  Lokapalontarhitatmaa Prasado
> Nilalohitah, Pavitramcha Mahaamschaiva Niyamo Niyamaashritah, Sarva
> Karmaa Swayambhuta Aadiradikaro Nidhih/ Sahasraaksho Vishaalaakshah
> Somo Nakshatra Saadhakah, Chandra Suryah Shanih Keturgraho
> Grahapatirvarah/ Aadyantalayaakartaacha Mriga Baanaarpanonaghah, Maha
> Tapaa Deerghatapaa Adeeno Deena Sadhakah/ Samvatsara Karo Mantrah
> Pramaanam Paramamtapah, Yogi Yojyo Mahaa Beejo Maha Retaa Maha Balah/
> Suvarnaretaah Sarvagjnah Subeejo Beeja Vahanah, Dashabaahustva nimisho
> Neelakanthah Umaapatih/ (1-20)
>
> **Translation for 1-20**
>
> Om- Sthirah or ‘Tishhateeti Sthirah’ or Stationary and Permanent;
> Sthaanavey or the Remote Monitoring Hinge of the Creation-‘Samsara
> Mandapasyaasya Mula Stambhaaya Shambhavey’; Prabhavey or Sarva Swami
> or the Over Lord of the Universe; Bheemah or the Source of Terror to
> Evil Forces; Pravaro or Sreshtha or the Best of All Beings; Varado or
> the Provider of Boons; Varah or the Boon Itself or what all built-in
> advantages that Maha Deva has provided to all the Beings as per the
> saying of –God! Count our Blessings; Sarvaatma or the One who spreads
> himself among each and every Being in their respective  Consciences;
> Sarva Vikhyatah or Highly Renowned all over the Universe; Sarvah or
> Vishwa Rupa or the Totality; Sarvakaro or the One who is the Supreme
> Performer; Bhavah or the Jagat Kaarana Bhuta or the Prime Sourcer;
> Jatiney or the One popular as having Jatajuta or matted and coarse
> hair; Charminey or the Wearer of Tiger/Elephant Skin; Shikhandiney or
> the One sporting Peacock feathers on His matted hair especially
> popular as a Kirata or hunter who chased the same animal hunted by
> Arjuna in a forest the incident of which is well-known in Maha
> Bharata; Sarvangah or His Physical Appearance is the representaion of
> the whole World; Sarvabhavanah or the One  who has the knowledge of
> the feelings of every Being in the Creation; Harascha or the Great
> Destroyer of all Beings at Pralaya or alternatively the obliteration
> of Sins : ‘Harati Paatakajaaam Smritimaatrenaa -panayateeti Harih’;
> Harinaakshacha or He has the attractive and liquid eyes of a deer;
> Sarva Bhuta Harah Prabhuh or the devastator of all the Beings at the
> Universal Extermination;  Pravrtitischa or He who is recognised by
> Karma Marga or by the Practice of Deeds of Virtue; Nivrittischa or He
> is realised by the Nivritti Marga or Path of Vairagya and the
> Other-Worldliness; Niyatah or the Highest Regulator of the Worlds;
> Shaswata or the Eternal and Everlasting; Dhruvah or the
> characterisation of Constancy and Stability; Smashanavaasi or the
> Resider of Burial Places as the Regulator of deaths and rebirths;
> Bhagavan or the Supreme Energy being the Source of ‘Chaturvidha
> Phalas’ viz. Dharma-Artha- Kaama- Moksha; Khacharah or the One moving
> about on the Skies-altervatively stated He who is search-worthy on the
> Hridayaakasha or the Mental Sky; Gocharah or the One realisable by
> senses or visions; Ardanah or the One who traps and punishes of the
> Vicious; Abhivadyah or the One who is saluted and worshipped always;
> Maha Karma or the One Symbol of Superior Actions; Tapaswi or the
> Exemplary Meditator for the Benefit of all the Beings; Bhuta bhavana
> /[dharana] or the One who creates / sustains the Pancha Bhutas of
> ‘Prithivya-apas-tejo-vaayu-raakaashaas’ viz. Earth-Water-Agni-Air-Sky;
> *Unmattaveshah or the One who feigned Madness to test the genuineness of the Sages at the Daruka Vana- [*A group of Sages who were great
> adept in ‘Karmakanada’ by way of daily homas and practice of
> abstinences of food and  physical pleasures was visited in the Daruka
> Vana by Parameshwara as a semi lunatic almost without clothes; this
> attracted the amorous attention of the family women and unmarried
> girls; the Rishis were annoyed at the provocative presence of  the
> lunatic and cursed him to drop his manhood and that was the Origin of
> Shiva Linga!];
>
> Pracchannah or He who conceals himself in varied forms; Sarva lokaya
> or of the Swarupa of the Three Lokas; Prajapatih or the Highest
> Authority of the Public in the Lokas; Maha Rupah or of the Magnificent
> and Gigantic Form; Maha Kayah or of the Huge Physique; Vrisha Rupah or
> of the Form of a Bull viz. Nandeeshwara; Maha Yashah or the Epitome of
> Reputation; Mahatma or of the Supreme Soul; Sarva Bhutatma  or the
> Undercurrent Soul of all the Beings in Srishti;  Vishwa Rupa or of the
> Appearance of the Universe in totality; Maha Hanuh or  of strong and
> oversized jay bones like that in the Varaha Incarnation of Vishnu;
> Lokapaala or the Top Administrator of Three  Lokas; Antarhitatma or of
> the Illustrious features like virtue, tranquility and equanimity;
> Prasadah of the Form of Mercy and Fulfillment; Nilalohitah or of Blue
> and Red complexions representing Prakriti or Maya and Purusha or Maha
> Deva; Pavitram cha or of Sanctity and Purity; Mahamschaiva or of the
> Outstanding and Awesome; Niyamah or the Essence of Discipline and
> Orderliness; Niyamaashritah or the One who encourages those observing
> regulations; Sarva karmaney or the Representation of all kinds of
> Acrivities; Swayambhuta or Self-Realised or Manifested by the Self;
> Adi or the Foremost whose Origin is unknown; Aadikara or the One who
> created Brahma the the First Creation; Nidhih or the Original Fund of
> Treasure; Sahasraaksha or of Thousands of Eye or the Omni-Scient;
> Visaalaksha or of the World-wide Vision; Somah or of the Form of
> Parvati characterising Prakri;  Nakshatra sadhakah or the Creator of
> the Star World;  Chandra or the Sign of Peacefulness and Lustor; Surya
> or of the Swarupa of Surya Deva; Shani or Saturn; Ketu; Graho or the
> rest of the Planets; Graha Pati or Parama Shiva the Head of the
> Grahas; Varah or the Greatest Boon to the Universe as He created such
> splendid facitities for Existence;  Adantalaya kartaacha or the One
> who is the Creator and Terminaor of the Universe; Mrigapraanaarpanah
> or  He who was responsible for releasing an arrow against the Deer
> despatched by the Munis in Daruka Forest as Maha Deva sought to test
> the devotion of the Munis; Anaghah or the Symbol of Sinlessness; Maha
> Tapah or He who performed unprecedented meditaion ever; Deergha Tapa
> or the One who achieved  the record-time Tapasya ever ie. Ajaraamara
> twa defying the definition of Time Measurement; Adeenah or he pretends
> to be helpless but actually is the Unique Provider of relief himself;
> Deena Sadhakah He is the Great Source of  Relief and Help to the Needy
> Himself; Samvatsara Karo or the One who regulates the Cycle of Years
> or of KalaMaana or the Calculations of Time on a repetitive basis;
> Mantrah or of the Swarupa of Omkara and other Mantras; Pramanaya or of
> the Supreme Standard which could never be surpassed by Devas,
> Maharshis and Maha Yogis alike; Paramam Tapah or the Unpararalleled
> and Unprecedented ‘Tapas’; Yogi or the One who is aware of the Perfect
> Equilibrium of Falsehood and Realiy or Maya and Paramatma; Yojyo or
> the practice of such achievement of Yoga; Maha Beejo or Shiva is the
> Extraordinary Gemirating Source of the Universe; Maha Reta or
> ‘Mahanmahatwam Reto yasya sa Maha Retaa’ or the Most Potent Sperm that
> creates  the Universe; Maha Balalah or the Epitome of Power and
> Strength; Suvarna Reta or of the of Golden Seeds enabling the Mammoth
> Task of Creation; Sarvagjnah or the All- Knowing; Subeejo or of the
> Seeds that are eternally effective and never faltering; Beeja Vahanah
> or the Permanent Carrier of Seeds from Nature to Fruition; Dasabahu
> ie. ‘Dasha Baahu dasha Bhujaah or of Ten Hands and Shoulders
> representing two of his own and of Eight Directions; Animishaaya or
> Nimesha rahita or the One who is unaffeted by time calculations of
> minutes or blinks of his eyes; Neelakanthaaya or the Blue Throated
> Deva as He devoured and preserved  the ‘Halaahala Visha’ or the blue
> poisonous flames to ensure the safety of the Worlds within his belly
> and outside it as the conflagrations appeared at the time of churning
> the Ocean of Milk by Deva Danavas to secure Amrita; Umapatih or the
> Swami of Pranava Swarupini Shakti called Uma);

My answer will be very very long if I were to quote the translation for the entire Stotram. So, for the remaining part, you need to visit the site.

And, if you are interested, then you can similarly learn the English translations of 3 other Shiva Sahasranama Stotras from [this page](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/CHATURVIDHA%20SHIVA%20SAHASRANAMA.html).

There you can get complete Sanskrit texts and translations of 4 Shiva Sahsranama Stotras (found in Linga Purana, Shiva Purana, Brahma Purana and Mahabharata).

The Mahabharata one is the one you asked about here.

Comment: excellent, thank you! 

Comment: No problem .. I already knew that Kamakoti website has the Chaturvida Shiva Sahsranama Stotras. So, my  task was easy here :) @LuckyPashu

Comment: i also found this one https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a017.htm

Comment: Yes that website has translation of the entire Mahabharata @LuckyPashu but the page I linked has translations of only the various Sahasranama Stotras.